# Can I let my florist cyclamen go dormant in a hot Mediterranean climate?

Tags: bulbs, storage

I had them in the past. Not for the time being.

While cyclamens go dormant throughout the summer, florist cyclamens seem unpredictable.

I live in a warm Mediterranean climate, zone 11. Temperatures seldom go down to 3C or 37F. Minimal temperatures in winter are normally around 10C or 50F.

The florist cyclamens fare the winter without the need to be sheltered indoors. Frost did not occur during my lifetime, but protection from hail is essential (This is the result of frost at a higher altitude. Ground temperature remains higher). In late spring, after flowering, they head-up to their dormancy stage just as the wild cyclamens do (Cyclamen Persicum and Cyclamen Coum, numbered [#6 and #11 respectively in this distribution map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclamen#/media/File:Cyclamen_distrib_map_east.jpg)). So the climate setting seems good for the florist cyclamens - or so it seems.

In an attempt to let them go dormant, one of two things may happen:

- 1st batch of tubers which go dormant: I water less and stop watering when all the remaining leaves start turning yellow. The summer has just started and the tubers have dried-up and shriveled. I end-up with wrinkled, hollow tubers.
- 2nd batch of tubers which break dormancy soon after, before spring ends: My understanding is that they have to be watered once more, but I let the soil dry before watering. This, however, did not make the tuber leaf to its fullest. The tuber died shortly after, probably from rotting.

Local nurseries in my area treat them as annuals, but I think this is a waste of plants (and money). Many even don't realize they develop a tuber because they couldn't hold them long enough! What was I doing wrong here? Maybe those hybrids have incompatible genes from different ancestral species with different climatic needs? They did not behave equally after all.